# Apple Music play count stats

Tags: apple-music

Is there a way to access play count or stats in general from an iPhone? Either Apple Music stats or local-content specific, doesn't necessarily matter, just can't seem to find anything like that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the native music app (iphone or tablet). It does write that data, it just doesn't give you access to it. I use [Marvis](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id971737469), which [lets you view  the play count and some other meta data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkLST.png). In the picture you can't see, but above there is the song, artist and album information names. You can view edit the play count. You can't sort based on the play count. It can [filter songs based on play count or star rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHigC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across **last.fm**, which allows a user to log their play count using their software, they even have an [API](https://www.last.fm/api/)! It's not only compatible with Apple Music, but pretty much [every major music streaming service](https://www.last.fm/about/trackmymusic).

There's a community on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lastfm/) and I recall seeing some cool time-series charts using this data too.

I'm surprised no one suggested it, as I would have liked to know about last.fm 2 years ago... therefore I will accept this answer as it's what I've been looking for this whole time.

Answer (score 3):

While it’s not possible as of now to view play counts in the Music app, other apps can do this. [Music Info](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1521580618?mt=8) is one that displays play count, last played, and other stats for your songs. It doesn’t require an Apple Music subscription - you can view metadata for any song in your music library. You can use it in the Music app too from the share sheet. Other apps I found haven’t been maintained or are too complex, so that’s why I built my own. :)

Comment: I just picked up your app @Jordan. I like it! It's very clean and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can see these details with a third party app

- Genre
- Rating
- Track #
- Composer
- Lyrics
- Date Added
- Last Played
- Last skipped
- Play Count
- Skip Count

---

[SmartPlaylist on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smartplaylist/id326071802?mt=8)

[SmartPlaylist Website](http://smartplaylist-iphone.blogspot.de/)

As of today the app costs $2.99 (in the US App Store). I bought it for the Smart Playlist functionality that I grew accustomed to with my iPod mini/iPod classic.

To see the play count and other statistics follow these steps

1. Play your desired song in the Music.app
2. Open SmartPlaylists.app
3. Tap **Menu** in the lower left
4. Select **Now Playing**
5. Double-tapping a field like "Skipped" or "Released" will show you the time as well.

Comment: The sad thing about this app to me is that you can't save these as any kind of iTunes playlists. I still tend to make my smart playlists on the iTunes desktop app, as those work fairly well on mobile devices. ITunes smart playlists thst are live updating, require you to restart the app to refresh the playlist. Not so great, but I can live with that. SmartPlaylist app, I think works a bit better on mobile devices, but it is not a great music player.

Answer (score 1):

On desktop Apple Music: File > Library > Export Library. You will get and .xml file, that contains info like this:

```
<key>2090</key>
<dict>
    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2090</integer>
    <key>Name</key><string>Give Life Back to Music</string>
    <key>Artist</key><string>Daft Punk</string>
    <key>Album Artist</key><string>Daft Punk</string>
    <key>Composer</key><string>pending</string>
    <key>Album</key><string>Random Access Memories</string>
    <key>Genre</key><string>Pop</string>
    <key>Kind</key><string>Apple Music AAC audio file</string>
    <key>Size</key><integer>10420405</integer>
    <key>Total Time</key><integer>274403</integer>
    <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Track Number</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Track Count</key><integer>13</integer>
    <key>Year</key><integer>2013</integer>
    <key>Date Modified</key><date>2015-07-05T08:14:34Z</date>
    <key>Date Added</key><date>2015-07-05T08:14:34Z</date>
    <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>256</integer>
    <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
    <key>Play Count</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Play Date</key><integer>3719860262</integer>
    <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2021-11-15T19:31:02Z</date>
    <key>Skip Count</key><integer>2</integer>
    <key>Skip Date</key><date>2021-11-15T19:31:09Z</date>
    <key>Release Date</key><date>2013-05-17T07:00:00Z</date>
    <key>Album Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
    <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
    <key>Loved</key><true/>
    <key>Album Loved</key><true/>
    <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Sort Album</key><string>Random Access Memories</string>
    <key>Sort Artist</key><string>Daft Punk</string>
    <key>Sort Name</key><string>Give Life Back to Music</string>
    <key>Persistent ID</key><string>C60A1C9D0A0989E9</string>
    <key>Track Type</key><string>Remote</string>
    <key>Apple Music</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Play count is probably what are you looking for.

Comment: How would this work on an iPhone (which is what the question is about)?

Comment: There is no reason to quibble. My answer helps to solve the mentioned task in general. It doesn't require an iPhone or any 3rd party software, so it is helpful.

Comment: From the question "Is there a way to access play count or stats in general from an iPhone". A desktop-based solution has its value, it's just not clear how it helps an iPhone user who may not even have a Mac or a PC.